# codecov fails in github actions

Tags: code-coverage, github-actions, codecov

#### backgrond

- my setup for codecov has worked well so far

  - you can regular updates with each pr commits [here](https://app.codecov.io/gh/iapicca/yak_packages)
  - I haven't change my repo settings
- as I've inadvertently pushed a folder that I wasn't supposed to,
  then I merged a [pr](https://github.com/iapicca/yak_packages/pull/136/) to remove said folder
- here is my [codecov.yml](https://github.com/iapicca/yak_packages/blob/master/codecov.yml)

#### issue

- on the aforementioned last pr linked above the github action ci complained with the log below

```
  _____          _
 / ____|        | |
| |     ___   __| | ___  ___ _____   __
| |    / _ \ / _` |/ _ \/ __/ _ \ \ / /
| |___| (_) | (_| |  __/ (_| (_) \ V /
 \_____\___/ \__,_|\___|\___\___/ \_/
                              Bash-1.0.3


==> git version 2.31.1 found
==> curl 7.68.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.68.0 OpenSSL/1.1.1f zlib/1.2.11 brotli/1.0.7 libidn2/2.2.0 libpsl/0.21.0 (+libidn2/2.2.0) libssh/0.9.3/openssl/zlib nghttp2/1.40.0 librtmp/2.3
Release-Date: 2020-01-08
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS brotli GSS-API HTTP2 HTTPS-proxy IDN IPv6 Kerberos Largefile libz NTLM NTLM_WB PSL SPNEGO SSL TLS-SRP UnixSockets
==> GitHub Actions detected.
    Env vars used:
      -> GITHUB_ACTIONS:    true
      -> GITHUB_HEAD_REF:   remove-speedtest
      -> GITHUB_REF:        refs/pull/136/merge
      -> GITHUB_REPOSITORY: iapicca/yak_packages
      -> GITHUB_RUN_ID:     {{I'll keep this for myself}}
      -> GITHUB_SHA:        {{I'll keep this for myself}}
      -> GITHUB_WORKFLOW:   CI
->  Issue detecting commit SHA. Please run actions/checkout with fetch-depth > 1 or set to 0
    project root: .
    Yaml found at: codecov.yml
==> Running gcov in . (disable via -X gcov)
==> Python coveragepy not found
==> Searching for coverage reports in:
    + .
    -> Found 7 reports
==> Detecting git/mercurial file structure
==> Reading reports
    + ./packages/yak_tween/coverage/lcov.info bytes=2228
    + ./packages/yak_utils/coverage.lcov bytes=687
    + ./packages/yak_test/coverage.lcov bytes=339
    + ./packages/stub/coverage.lcov bytes=678
    + ./packages/yak_runner/coverage.lcov bytes=6429
    + ./packages/yak_widgets/coverage/lcov.info bytes=1444
    + ./packages/yak_error_handler/coverage.lcov bytes=1017
==> Appending adjustments
    https://docs.codecov.io/docs/fixing-reports
    + Found adjustments
==> Gzipping contents
        8.0K    /tmp/codecov.yP3SSF.gz
==> Uploading reports
    url: https://codecov.io
    query: branch=remove-speedtest&commit={{I'll keep this for myself}}
    &build={{I'll keep this for myself}}&build_url=http%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fiapicca%2Fyak_packages%2Factions%2Fruns%2F911981303&name=&tag=&slug=iapicca%2Fyak_packages&service=github-actions&flags=&pr=136&job=CI&cmd_args=

->  Pinging Codecov
https://codecov.io/upload/v4?package=bash-1.0.3&token=secret&branch=remove-speedtest&commit={{I'll keep this for myself}}&build={{I'll keep this for myself}}&build_url=http%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fiapicca%2Fyak_packages%2Factions%2Fruns%2F911981303&name=&tag=&slug=iapicca%2Fyak_packages&service=github-actions&flags=&pr=136&job=CI&cmd_args=
{'detail': ErrorDetail(string='Unable to locate build via Github Actions API. Please upload with the Codecov repository upload token to resolve issue.', code='not_found')}
404
==> Uploading to Codecov
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100  5026  100   171  100  4855   1000  28391 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 29220
100  5026  100   171  100  4855   1000  28391 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 29220
    {'detail': ErrorDetail(string='Unable to locate build via Github Actions API. Please upload with the Codecov repository upload token to resolve issue.', code='not_found')}
```

- the suggested fix is quite obscure to me

```
{'detail': ErrorDetail(string='Unable to locate build via Github Actions API. Please upload with the Codecov repository upload token to resolve issue.', code='not_found')}
```

#### request

as I don't really want to run anything locally can someone help me to fix the issue
inside the CI

thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Codecov has some heisenberg issues. If you don't have a token, please add one otherwise try to:

- Force-push to retrigger Codecov
- Rotate your token.

Comment: What's a heisenberg issue in this context?

Comment: @Tag, generally referring to bugs/issues that conveniently disappear when you try to observe/fix them: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle, see also "Heisenbugs".

Answer (score 3):

Refreshing my codecov token and reinstalling the plugin worked for me.

Comment: Can confirm that regenerating the token fixes it. Also for public repos.

Comment: Edit: Only fixes it shortly. It reappears after time.

Comment: Yes, indeed. :(
But they are tracking it in https://github.com/codecov/codecov-action/issues/330

Comment: Seems to be fixed.

Comment: I regenerated the token and it fixed the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

**NOTE**:
This answer refers to the new [uploader](https://about.codecov.io/blog/introducing-codecovs-new-uploader/). You can also use `codecov`'s [action](https://github.com/codecov/codecov-action) instead.

I had failing [builds](https://github.com/Nelson-Gon/pyfdc/runs/3900111676?check_suite_focus=true) although I had `steps` setup correctly. In my case what fixed the builds was to change the "alpine" to "linux" in the uploader link and explicitly provide an environmental variable named `CODECOV_TOKEN`.

```
- name: Upload reports to codecov
      env:
        CODECOV_TOKEN: ${{secrets.CODECOV_TOKEN}}
      run: | 
       curl -Os https://uploader.codecov.io/latest/linux/codecov
       find . -iregex "codecov.*"
       chmod +x codecov 
       ./codecov -t ${CODECOV_TOKEN}
```

See the entire workflow file at [this](https://github.com/Nelson-Gon/pyfdc/blob/master/.github/workflows/build-package.yaml) repo.

Comment: Adding the CODECOV_TOKEN secret as an environmental variable actually fixed the issue for me! I'm surprised it wasn't enough to add it as a secret.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue today.

Seems related to [Issue #330](https://github.com/codecov/codecov-action/issues/330) being tracked from their GitHub page.

Last comment (as of this writing) suggests that the issue should have been fixed about an hour ago, but my latest PRs still ran into it. I'll post an update if I can confirm it's fixed for me.

**UPDATE:** This has been fixed with [release of version 1.5.2](https://github.com/codecov/codecov-action/releases/tag/v1.5.2) of the codecov action.

Comment: it doesn't seem like it, we're hitting the same issue constantly.